# Inv-Wishart against LKJ prior for multivariate meta analysis model

Tags: multivariate-analysis, meta-analysis, stan, inverse-wishart

I am working in Stan on a three-dimensional multivariate problem. The model assumed is that the data are from a multivaraite normal with study level mean and covariance matrix, with the covariance matrix given. The study level mean has a mutlivaraite normal prior whose mean are assumed independent normal prior and covaraince matrix is assumed either an Inv-Wishart prior or an LKJ prior on correlation matrix with half cauchy on each variance components.

I run a bivariate version of this and everything works fine, both priors for covariance matrix produce similar results(perhaps I got enough data so it won't matter?).

But when it comes to the three-dimensional, Stan has no problem running Inv-Wishart model but always gets divergent transitions errors for LKJ prior, which confuses me because I always assume that LKJ prior should have a better performance compared to Inv-Wishart. I am totally clueless. Tried reparameterzation but no luck, see below. Anyone has ideas on why this is?

````
data {
  int<lower=0> n;
  vector[3] y[n];
  real<lower=0> se[1, 3, n];
  vector<lower=-1,upper=1>[3] rw;
}

transformed data {
  matrix[3,3] L_S[n];
  for (j in 1:n){
    matrix[3,3] S;

    S[1,1] = square(se[1,1,j]);
    S[1,2] = rw[1] * se[1,1,j] * se[1,2,j];
    S[1,3] = rw[2]*se[1,1,j]*se[1,3,j];
    S[2,1] = S[1,2];
    S[2,2] = square(se[1,2,j]);
    S[2,3] = rw[3]*se[1,2,j]*se[1,3,j];
    S[3,1] = S[1,3];
    S[3,2] = S[2,3];
    S[3,3] = square(se[1,3,j]);

    L_S[j] = cholesky_decompose(S);
  }
}

parameters {
  vector[3] mu_raw[n];
  vector[3] beta;
  cholesky_factor_corr[3] L_Omega;
  vector<lower=0>[3] tau;
}

transformed parameters {
  vector[3] mu[n];
  matrix[3,3] mu_Cov = diag_pre_multiply(tau, L_Omega);

  for (m in 1:n){
    // Implies mu[m] ~ multi_normal_cholesky(beta, mu_Cov) 
    mu[m] = beta + mu_Cov * mu_raw[n];
  }
}

model {
  for(m in 1:n) {
    mu_raw[m] ~ std_normal(); 
  }
  // Priors
  L_Omega ~ lkj_corr_cholesky(2);
  tau ~ cauchy(0, 2.5);

  beta ~ normal(0,10);

  // Data
  for (i in 1:n){
    y[i] ~ multi_normal_cholesky(mu[i], L_S[i]);
  }
}



```
````